# Add custom data field column to contribution tab

Tags: custom-fields, contributions

Is there a way to add additional fields in the contribution tab on a contacts record?

Comment: Are you trying to create an new custom field against contribution record?

Answer (score 3):

As Jon says you will need to write some code, it wouldn't be difficult to implement though.

What I tend to do is create a Civi extension or use an existing one as explained [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension).

Once done, you could use [hook_civicrm_searchColumns](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_searchColumns) to add an extra column header as explained [here](https://civicrm.org/blogs/lobo/introducing-hookcivicrmsearchcolumns-modify-search-results-meet-your-needs) and then create a custom template, as documented  [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customize+Built-in,+Profile,+Contribution+and+Event+Registration+Screens), of the file `templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Selector.tpl` to output the value needed.

The downside of the searchColumns hooks is that you wont be able to sort the data for that specific value.

Hope that gives more insights.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question if you're looking for a means to add a column without coding.  If so, the answer is "no".  This is a good example of what's hoped to be possible with the CiviCRM 5 form builder, but that's still a ways off.

If you're able to code, or know/hire someone who does, the relevant file is `templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Selector.tpl`.

Comment: In order to add/modify a column in the summary tab or the built-in Contribution search, I believe the right file to target is templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Selector.tpl

Comment: Note: Andrei's answer is much better than mine!